# List to tree structure

Tags: php

I have the following sample array list;

```
$relationships = ['contact', 'property', 'contact.type1', 'contact.type2', 'contact.type1.color1', 'contact.type1.color2'];
```

I want a structure like this;

```
[
    contact => [ 
                 type1 => [
                             color1 => [], 
                             color2 => []
                          ], 
                 type2 => [] 
               ], 
    property => []
]
```

I created the following code;

```
start();

function start()
{
    $myTree = array();

    $relations = ['contact', 'property', 'contact.type1', 'contact.type2', 'contact.type1.color1', 'contact.type1.color2'];

    foreach ($relations as $relation) {

        $myTree = getRelationTree($relation, $myTree);
    }

    var_dump($myTree);
}

function getRelationTree($name, $tree)
{
    $sections = explode('.', $name);

    $main = array_shift($sections);

    if (!array_search($main, $tree)) {
        $tree[$main] = [] ;
    }

    // Has nested relationships
    if (count($sections) > 0) {
        $children  = [];
        $children[] = getRelationTree(join('.',$sections), $children);

        $tree[$main] = $children;
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

However, the results I get is missing `color1` as per expected results above.

Could you tell me what's wrong with my code and how I can fix it to give me the desired results? Thanks

Comment: i really don't understand by which logic you want to transform array to that desired formatted array ? would please tell me ?

Comment: This is a business requirement. The example I gave here is just a sample of the structure I will receive and the structure I need to output.

Comment: if there is no logic behind this, so why don't you make manually hardcord that type of array

Comment: @BunkerBoy I'm not the op, but the logic is after the dot, you make it a child of the array. Compare the dots and the array levels...everytime there is a dot, you go deep a level, and they are grouped by name.. (that is, if I got it right)

Comment: yes i also found that but i want to confirm with OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just wrote simpler code using references instead of recurency.

Take a look my code, it contains comments saying what's happening:

```
<?php

$relationships = ['contact', 'property', 'contact.type1', 'contact.type2', 'contact.type1.color1', 'contact.type1.color2'];

$tree = []; 
foreach($relationships as $path) {
    $parts = explode('.', $path);

    //represents current position in current $path
    $currentNode = &$tree;

    foreach($parts as $part) {
        //if this part doesn't exist yet, let's create it
        if(empty($currentNode[$part])) {
            $currentNode[$part] = [];
        }
        //move forward in out $path position
        $currentNode = &$currentNode[$part];
    }
    //after we finish a particular path, we reset the position.
    unset($currentNode);
}
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/o3MGP

EDIT: Here's explanation of your mistake:

As I've analyzed your code, I can see your mistake in your function `getRelationTree()` here:

```
// Has nested relationships
if (count($sections) > 0) {
    $children  = []; 
    $children[] = getRelationTree(implode('.',$sections), $children);

    $tree[$main] = $children; // <==this line exactly
}
```

You are overriding already existing values.

So when your tree already has parsed `'contact.type1.color1'` path, and you're parsing `'contact.type1.color2'`, you will override `$tree['contact']` which already has values from `'type1.color1'` with new subtree of `type1.color2`. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to the other answer, using **recursiveness** (copy-paste ready):

```
$relationships = ['contact', 'property', 'contact.type1', 'contact.type2', 'contact.type1.color1', 'contact.type1.color2'];

$arr = array();

foreach($relationships as $value){
    add($arr, $value);
}

function add(&$arr, $value){
    if(strpos($value, '.') !== false){ // if there are sublevels
        $tmp = explode('.', $value, 2); // separate first from rest of levels
        $item = $tmp[0]; // get what's before first dot
        $children = $tmp[1]; // get what's after the first dot
        if(empty($arr[$item])){ // if not yet created, create item
            $arr[$item] = array();
        }
        add($arr[$item], $children); // add the item's child / children
        return; // prevent from overriding
    }
    $arr[$value] = array();
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```